# Azure devops server 2019 migration to Azure Devop services

Tags: azure-devops, azure-active-directory, database-migration

As the Pre-Requisite For migration , we have AADDS(Azure Active directory Domain Services) used instead of on premise Active directory
So got error during validation with identitymapLog.csv file
""No Match Found (Check Azure AD Sync)""
AD synch tool cannot be used for AADDS .So any suggestions on solving this issues?

Answer (score 0):

After opening the log directory noted in the data migration tool's output we could see the file `IdentityMapLog.csv`, it contains the generated mapping of AD to Azure AD identities.  It's recommended that you review the identity map log file, `IdentityMapLog.csv`, for completeness before kicking off an import.

According to the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/migrate/migration-import?view=azure-devops#understand-the-identity-map-log-file): You and your Azure AD admin will need to investigate those users marked as **No Match Found (Check Azure AD Sync)** to understand why they aren't part of your Azure AD Connect sync.

We could refer to this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/migrate/migration-import?view=azure-devops#prepare-command) for more details.

Comment: Yes followed that, but found that SID of Azure ADDS  and SID of Azure active directory is not same .. so on that note is there any way to customized the identityLogMap.csv with UPN attribute instead of SID

Answer (score 0):

Yes followed that, but found that SID of Azure ADDS and SID of Azure active directory is not same .. so on that note is there any way to customized the identityLogMap.csv with UPN attribute instead of SID –